# What does feedforward inversion mean in the context of convolution and catastrophic codes?

Tags: terminology, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

i'm reading the article of J. L. Massey and M. K. Sain, "Inverses of Linear Sequential Circuits" (Date of Publication - 
April 1968) ([here](http://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/archive/massey_pub/pdf/BI413.pdf)) and i cannot understand - what is "feedforward inversion"?

They give a short description of circles in convolution codes and a little bit description about catastrophic codes (codes that makes an infinite amount of errors on decoding if there was a couple of errors in channel).

Can anyone explain the term "feedforward inversion", and what do they mean by delay in that regard?

P.S. i'm interested in this theme because i want to understand the proof of Theorem 1 in that article, no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper deals with sequential encoding and decoding of codes. Maybe you have heard of "block codes": these codes take a message $M\in \{0,1\}^k$, perform some computation, and then output a code-word $c_M \in \{0,1\}^n$.<sup>(1)</sup>. A main drawback of encoding systems for such codes is that need to know **the entire** message $M$ in order to output $c_M$.

This is not the case in convolution code.

#### Sequential circuits

Convolution codes are usually designed so that there is a very simple and *sequential* encoding algorithm. By "sequential" I mean that the system reads $M$ bit by bit, and immediately<sup>(2)</sup> outputs some part of $c_M$. Say, if the rate is $k/n=1/2$, then for every bit of $M$ given as an input to the encoder, the encoding system outputs the next $2$ bits of the codeword (even without knowing the rest of $M$). After the entire input $M$ is fed into the encoder, we will get the entire codeword $c_M$.

This sequential nature of encoding is what the paper means by "feed-forward": you always input the next part of the data, and that's enough for the system to proceed and give output, as a function on the current state of the encoder. This is/was crucial in memoryless implementations (those can't hold the past bits of the message $M$), or implementations that could not wait to have the entire $M$ due to the large delay incurred (those don't know the future bits of the message $M$).

Thus, a "feedforward inverse" is simply a **sequential** decoding algorithm. ("inverse" is the algorithm that inverses the code, that is, the decoding system).

#### Delay

The delay $L$ is explained in the first paragraph of the paper:   (below, not a precise quote)

> An inverse with delay $L$, for a sequential circuit with $k$ inputs and $n$ outputs *[= a decoder for the encoder]*, is a sequential circuit with $n$ inputs and $k$ outputs, that cascaded with the encoder, yields an overall sequential circuit with delay $L$.

That is, take the encoder, and connect the decoder immediately to the output of the encoder. Now start feeding the input into the encoder. $L$ is the amount of "clocks" until you see the same bit at the output of the decoder.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The alphabet needs not be binary, this is just for simplicity.

<sup>(2)</sup> Or after a fixed number of clocks.

Comment: wow. now it is much more clear ;) well, when i was reading this paper, i meant under convolution coder something like this  http://c2n.me/3jeYppX ( the (+) is XOR, isn't it? )
and i really didn't got, what is the "delay" was meant, because by default i filled those "boxes" with zeros, so, for example, if i'll feed a 111...111 sequence to this coder, i'll get (by codewords for every information bit): 10 11 00 00 00 00 ... so i really didn't got, what is "delay". now it is clear, thank You!

Comment: the another point is - i know another interpretation of that theorem, it sounds like "The code is NOT catastrophic (i.e. the code that makes finite-weightened code for infinite-weightened input vector) when and only when GCD of determinants of all submatrixes (k x k) of G (k is one of parameters of code, (n, k, d)) is = x**s, where s≥0", so i don't understand, is it the same theorem or not... =(

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar enough with that paper to answer your other question.